# can a thread of activity to survive when activity restart?

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a thread A that have a connection Bluetooth toward a serial devices.
When activity restarts (an example rotation of screen), the thread die with the activity so the connection Bluetooth end. Is there a method for survive the thread A when activity restart or to survive the connection Bluetooth? without the use of service, my teacher tell me don't use it for this application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` to retain your thread. See [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2011/07/12/threads-activity-lifecycle/) that covers this case.